# Problems getting Zurb's Social Icons to display

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I have a test site set up with Zurb Foundation. I'm trying to get Zurb's svg enabled social icons to work but the icon itself won't display. It does display the little shadow behind the icons but none of the icons display.

I have a test site set up here that has an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure your server allows the SVC mime type.

If you change the paths to your .svg to point to zurb's demo, they work just fine.

```
.svg .fc-webicon.facebook {
background: url("http://www.zurb.com/playground/playground/social-webicons/images/fc-webicon-facebook.svg");
}
```

Comment: Also, I would suggest moving foundation.css to the top of your css declarations.
foundation.css
app.css
other.css

Comment: Great! Mime types often catch me too.

Comment: how do i add the svc mime type? found no info about it in the whole universe. i use apache webserver.

Comment: nevermind, i had to download the `foundation-icons.ttf` and `foundation-icons.woff` files